# Gettext for custom field checkbox values

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, localization

I have a custom field (created with ACF) that allows the author to choose from several options (in admin) and where these choices are displayed on the front-end. The code producing the custom field is :

```
array (
'key' => 'field_52dcf154e272e',
'label' => __('Selling Points', 'mytheme' ),
'name' => 'selling_points',
'type' => 'checkbox',
'instructions' => __('Check 4 items', 'mytheme' ),
'choices' => array (
    'Bed linens included key' => __('Bed linens included value', 'mytheme'),
    'Full bed linens included' =>__('Full bed linens included', 'mytheme'),
    'Free WIFI and Internet Access' => __('Free WIFI and Internet Access', 'mytheme' ),
    'Free (in-room) WIFI' =>__('Free (in-room) WIFI', 'mytheme' ), 
    'Breakfast included' => __('Breakfast included', 'mytheme' ),
    'Safe provided in room' => __('Safe provided in room', 'mytheme' ),
    'Individual room key' => __('Individual room key', 'mytheme' ),
    ),
'layout' => 'vertical',
),
```

The problem is that the value is displayed in the admin choices and the key is currently displayed on the front-end. In teh page template I have the following code:

```
$count= 0;
$points = get_field_object('selling_points');

foreach ( $points['value'] as $point ){
    if($count < 4 ){
        printf(__('<li class="bullet-item">%s</li>', 'mytheme' ), $point);
        $count++;
    }
}
```

when I `var_dump($points)` I get:

```
Array
(
    [key] => field_52dcf154e272e
    [label] => Selling Points
    [name] => selling_points
    [_name] => selling_points
    [type] => checkbox
    [order_no] => 1
    [instructions] => Check 4 items
    [required] => 0
    [id] => acf-field-selling_points
    [class] => checkbox
    [conditional_logic] => Array
        (
            [status] => 0
            [allorany] => all
            [rules] => 0
        )

    [choices] => Array
        (
            [Bed linens included key:] => Bed linens included value
            [Full bed linens included] => Full bed linens included
            [Free WIFI and Internet Access] => Free WIFI and Internet Access
            [Free (in-room) WIFI] => Free (in-room) WIFI
            [Breakfast included] => Breakfast included
            [Safe provided in room] => Safe provided in room
            [Individual room key] => Individual room key
        )

    [layout] => vertical
    [default_value] => 
    [value] => Array
        (
            [0] => Bed linens included key:
            [1] => Free WIFI and Internet Access
            [2] => Petit déjeuner inclus
            [3] => Safe provided in room
        )

)
```

So apparently AFC is getting the value based on the key. How can I then take the values in the array `[value]` and convert them into a gettext calls?

Comment: Using Variables in a gettext-context is not a wise thing to do, since gettext searches your files for hard coded strings to be translated.

Comment: So I need to echo the contents of the variable inside a gettext call? How could I get around this?